# Call to a member function roles() on array (Laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, laravel, migration, roles

I'm basically new to Laravel. I keep getting this **"Call to member function roles() on array"** error.

I'm trying to add a user's role into my database which has many to many relation. I've looked for an answer for this everywhere and the results said I just needed to add a return statement in my function. **But I already have a return statement and it still doesn't work.**

So here are my codes.


**User.php model**

```
<?php

class User extends Model implements Authenticatable
{

    use \Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;

    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';    
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_fname', 'user_mname', 'user_lname', 'user_ptitle', 'user_sex', 'user_civilstatus', 'user_nationality', 'user_bday', 'user_bplace', 'user_address', 'user_mobile', 'user_landline'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function login(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Login', 'user_id');
    }

    public function registercoop(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\CoopDetails', 'coop_id');
    }

    public function listcomaker(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\LoanCoMaker', 'user_id');
    }

    public function roles(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Role', 'role_users', 'user_id', 'role_id');
    }


}
```

**Role.php model**

```
<?php

class Role extends Model
{

    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','role_users', 'role_id', 'user_id');
    }

}
```

**Lines from my AccountController.php where the saving to database happens**

```
        $user=[
        'user_email' =>  $email,
        'password'  => $password
    ];

    $count = DB::table('users')
            ->where('created_at', '>=', 'CURRENT_DATE')
            ->count(); //Count entries for that day.


    $year = Carbon::now()->year;
    $month = Carbon::now()->month;


    if ($count<100 && $count>10){
        $count="0".$count;
        $user_id = $year.$month.$count;
    }
    else if ($count<10){
        $count="00".$count;
        $user_id = $year.$month.$count;
    }
    else{
        $user_id = $year.$month.$count;
    }

    $user->roles()->attach($user_superadmin);
```

**P.S** I actually have made it work the first time. I just renamed my old model *UserType.php* into *Role.php*, updated my migrations, seeders, controllers, models, etc. and then it stopped working properly.

Can someone help me point out what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you paste the whole Role.php and User.php?

Comment: `attach` takes id or array of id instead of object!

Comment: @RobinDirksen I've  attached the photos. Please take a look.

Comment: @SaumyaRastogi how do I fix that?

Comment: @Eggnog654 Please don't post images of code. Code is text, so post it as such.

Comment: `as` is not needed in your `use` on the `Auth` class

Comment: @RobinDirksen I've also added the line from the **AccountController.php** from where the `user_id` is generated.

Comment: @Eggnog654 the error means exactly what it says, `$user` is an **array** you declared it in `AccountController.php`

Comment: @Saad my `$user = new User` which happens to be the model

Comment: You did not create a `new User` in `AccountController.php`, `$user` is an array hence when you are calling `$user->roles()->attach($user_superadmin);` it is giving the error

Comment: Guuuys! I think I got it to work! 

First, I declared another `$roleuser = new User;`
then I changed the line `$user->roles()->attach($user_superadmin);` into `$roleuser->roles()->attach($user_superadmin);` 

Now it's working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first make the User, this can be done through the following:

```
$user_data = [
    'user_email' =>  $email,
    'password'  => $password
];

$user = new User();
$user->email = $user_data['user_email'];
$user->password = encrypt($user_data['password']);

$user->save(); //save the user to the database
//$user now contains the user_id (if its successfully created)

$count = DB::table('users')
        ->where('created_at', '>=', 'CURRENT_DATE')
        ->count(); //Count entries for that day.


$year = Carbon::now()->year;
$month = Carbon::now()->month;


if ($count<100 && $count>10){
    $count="0".$count;
    $user_id = $year.$month.$count;
}
else if ($count<10){
    $count="00".$count;
    $user_id = $year.$month.$count;
}
else{
    $user_id = $year.$month.$count;
}

$user->roles()->attach($user_superadmin);
```

Hope this works!

Comment: Odd, I already have that line. I made a new variable for that instead and it worked. :)

Comment: Now I'm having issues with the `user_id` not having a value when the `roles()` function is being executed.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're using a pivot table for the roles?  In that case you want a `belongsToMany()` relationship on your User class instead of the `hasMany()`

```
public function roles(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'role_users', 'user_id', 'role_id');
}
```

See [Laravel Docs Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Then you need to create an instance of the `App\User` to be able to access that relationship.  Your code is calling a function on the array of `['user_email' => $email, 'password' => $password]`.  You have to create the user first or retrieve one but it needs to be that user model.

```
// Create User
$user = new User();
$user->user_email = $email;
$user->password = encrypt($password);
$user->save();
// OR retrieve user
$user = User::where('your_column', $your_column_value)->get();

$count = User::where('created_at', '>=', 'CURRENT_DATE')->count(); //Count entries for that day.

$year = Carbon::now()->year;
$month = Carbon::now()->month;


if ($count<100 && $count>10){
    $count="0".$count;
    $user_id = $year.$month.$count;
}
else if ($count<10){
    $count="00".$count;
    $user_id = $year.$month.$count;
}
else{
    $user_id = $year.$month.$count;
}

$user->roles()->attach($user_superadmin);
```

Comment: I have changed that line to `belongsToMany`. I got it to working, but somehow my `user_id` is **null** when the `$roleuser->roles()->attach($user_superadmin);` is executed.

`$roleuser->roles()->attach($user_superadmin);` is the edited version of `$user->roles()->attach($user_superadmin);`

Comment: You need to save it to the user first then.  `$user->user_id = $user_id; $user->save();`

Comment: Thanks for the patience but I'm really lost right now. I've saved the `user_id` already using this:

 `DB::table('users')
            ->where("user_email", $data['email'])
            ->update(['user_id' => $user_id]);`

It's saving but the error persists.

Comment: I found the answer to my problem here in my new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41245657/integrity-constraint-violation-1048-column-user-id-cannot-be-null-error-occur