# Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null error occurs when assigning roles (Laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration, roles

[Here's what I was doing before the error occurred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41228832/call-to-a-member-function-roles-on-array-laravel-5-3/41229554?noredirect=1#comment69662442_41229554)

I'm trying to assign a role for a user from my `users` and `roles` table in a new table called `role_users'.

**Role.php model**

```
class Role extends Model{  
  public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','role_users', 'role_id', 'user_id');
  }
}
```

**User.php model**

```
class User extends Model implements Authenticatable
{
  use \Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;

  public function roles(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'role_users', 'user_id', 'role_id');
  }    
}
```

I keep getting the error in this line from my **AccountController.php**

```
$roleuser = new User;
$user_superadmin = Role::where('role_desc', 'Superadmin')->first();
$roleuser->roles()->attach($user_superadmin); /*this line specifically*/
```

I'm having `Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into 'role_users' ('role_id', 'user_id') values (1, ))`. The `users table` is already updated and the `user_id` has already been saved to the database.

Can someone help me? I must have overlooked some important stuff.

Comment: MY Schema sense is tingling. Shouldn't A `User` have many roles, rather than belong to?

Comment: You mean use hasMany instead? Yes I was using that one last night. But I'm getting a `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::attach()` error. It should have a belongsToMany relationship on both sides.

Comment: It doesn't make sense. In relationships Model A belong to Model B and Model B hasMany Model A's. Having them both belongTo each seems to go against the principle.

Comment: Hmm. It must be because I'm using a pivot table which happens to be required for many-to-many relationships. But for a user-role relationship, it's only a one-to-many so I don't really need a pivot table, and just save it to my `users` table directly. Must be why it looks so contradicting?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I must change this one to one-to-many instead. I was just following this tutorial on Youtube. Your comment got me into a research. Got it better now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is that you don't attach role to any existing user, you just run:

```
$roleuser = new User;
```

to create user object that is not save to database.

You should rather do something like this:

```
$roleuser = User::find(1); // find user with id 1
$user_superadmin = Role::where('role_desc', 'Superadmin')->first();
$roleuser->roles()->attach($user_superadmin); /*this line specifically*/
```

or

```
$roleuser = User::create(['name' => 'Sample user']); // create sample user
$user_superadmin = Role::where('role_desc', 'Superadmin')->first();
$roleuser->roles()->attach($user_superadmin); /*this line specifically*/
```

You should also don't use `$roleuser` variable here, because it's obviously `$user`

Comment: I know that. Hehe. But I used $user as the variable last night but I got an error. I tried changing it and that's when it worked.. until I got this error.

Comment: This worked! I used `$user = User::find($user_id);` instead before running the last two lines since I already have a user registered to the database.

Answer (score 1):

You can't attach relation to non existing user. Try to create user first:

```
$roleuser = User::create(['name' => 'John']); // Instead of new User;
```

Or fetch user from DB:

```
$roleuser = User:find(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while working with Laravel 9.
you Should create the user before adding permissions.

```
$user = new User();
```

Then make your action
at last Save your User

```
$user->save();
```